# How create image overlays? change edges color

Tags: matlab, cat, sobel

How create an image overlays? change edges color:
For changing edges to green, at first I used 'sobel' however the overlay part have is an error: "IMG must be an array of either grayscale or RGB images:  writeVideo(writer,double(out));" Why?

```
    out_red(BW)=0;
    out_green(BW)=255;
    out_blue(BW)=0;


    writeVideo(writer,double(uint8(out)));


close(writer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set by mistake the entire img as each color channel, it should be like that instead:

```
out_red=img(:,:,1);
out_green=img(:,:,2);
out_blue=img(:,:,3);
```

and the end do `writeVideo(writer, uint8(out));`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
redChannel = inputImage(:, :, 1);
greenChannel = inputImage(:, :, 2);
blueChannel = inputImage(:, :, 3);
writeVideo(writer, uint8(out));
```

The `writeVideo` class expect data to be `uint8` if its range is {0, 1, 2, ..., 255}.
If you want to use `single` or `double` data you need to scale it back to [0, 1] range.

Comment: by doing so there is an error : "IMG must be an array of either grayscale or RGB images" then I was trying this: "writeVideo(writer, double(uint8(out)));" but still got the error:"IMG must be an array of either grayscale or RGB images". Why?

Comment: You didn't extract each channel by itself. See my edit.